# MySQL - Merge two columns into one with comma

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge two columns into one with comma separated. I did try concat function but no success. How can I merge them with a comma? I really need to move subcat_id to cat_id with a comma.

```
cat_id  subcat_id
49,417  417
49,416  416
49      415
49      414
```

[image: example]

Comment: _I'm trying to merge two columns into one with comma separated.._ No! Don't do that! **Stop** exactly here and think about **normalization**

Comment: @B001ᛦ Denormalization is combining multiple *rows*.

Comment: `CONCAT()` should have worked. Show what you tried.

Comment: concat_ws is work for output but my question is how can I update cat_id column with output?

Answer (score 0):

Try [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', cat_id, subcat_id)
FROM table...
```

Comment: SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', cat_id, subcat_id) FROM products
I run the SQL but nothing happened.

Comment: Usagi, I need your help for update cat_id can you please give me instruction? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is simple=;

Update table set field CONCAT_WS(',', cat_id, sub_cat_id)
where field=field